# nil:NilClass method error

Tags: ruby

I am getting a nil:NilClass error. I believe this is because @dna_to_rna is not defined at the time it is called. 
My question is why? 
I've defined an initialize method and a reader method. I feel I'm missing something basic here...

```
    class Complement
      attr_reader :dna_to_rna

      def initialize
      @dna_to_rna = { G: 'C', C: 'G', T: 'A', A: 'U'}
      end

      def self.of_dna(dna)
        binding.pry
        # dna.gsub(/[GCTA]/,'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U' )
        raise exception(ArgumentError) unless dna.each_char{|c| @dna_to_rna.keys.join.include?(c)}
        dna.gsub(/#{@dna_to_rna.keys.join}/,@dna_to_rna.values)
      end
end
```

Here is the test:

```
  def
   test_rna_complement_of_cytosine_is_guanine
    assert_equal 'G', Complement.of_dna('C')
  end
```

Here is the Error message:

```
Finished in 0.001247s, 801.9246 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ComplementTest#test_rna_complement_of_cytosine_is_guanine:
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/tom/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/complement.rb:10:in `block in of_dna'
    /Users/tom/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/complement.rb:10:in `each_char'
    /Users/tom/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/complement.rb:10:in `of_dna'
    complement_test.rb:8:in `test_rna_complement_of_cytosine_is_guanine'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

For context: I want to use the @dna_to_rna as a local variable in initialize  because I want to write DRY code and intend to use the same attribute when I write the opposite method which converts rna_to_dna.
I know I could define this hash in the method but why won't it work in the initialize?

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting in full?

Comment: Hi @Mike, I've added the error and the test, as well as my reasons for writing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def self.of_dna(dna)
```

is a class method, called as `Complement.of_dna(dna)`. If that's what you're doing (you are), then naturally you get the NilClass error, as @dna_to_rna is undefined. It should be

```
  def of_dna(dna)
```

so that it can be called as an instance method, on:

```
c=Complement.new
c.of_dna(dna)
```

And your test becomes:

```
def test_rna_complement_of_cytosine_is_guanine
  assert_equal 'G', Complement.new.of_dna('C')
end
```

Or, you can leave it as `def self.to_dna`, and move the instance variable into the `of_dna` method as a simple local variable, or out of the block and make it a constant:

```
module Complement
  DNA_TO_RNA = {...}
```

and it's a module, because you don't need to `Complement.new` ever. Your test then remains as you have it.

Also, unrelated, I recommend you write the line thus:

```
    raise ArgumentError if dna.each_char.any?{|c| !@dna_to_rna.keys.include?(c)}
```

`all?` returns true if every invocation of the block was true. `any?` returns true if any invocation of the block was true, and will return slightly early as an true-value will cause it to short-circuit.

Probably an even better way exists, perhaps this:

```
raise ArgumentError unless dna.gsub(/[#{@dna_to_rna.keys.join}]/, '').empty?
```

This one removes any of the keys from the string, and if the `dna` string isn't empty after that, we have an extra character, hence `raise`. I prefer the version with `all?` though, as it is quite readable.

Comment: Hi @Satya, I have included the test which I want to make pass. If i change the code as you say I recieve:
 'NoMethodError: undefined method `of_dna' for Complement:Class'

Comment: Thank you for your help @Satya it really is appreciated. I've decided I was trying to be too ambitious for my current level of competence...
I tried a module and DNA_TO_RNA as a constant but can't get it working.. I've gone back to the method where I will be repeating myself for each conversion.

Although creating a module and using a constant didn't solve the problem; your  answer did help me partially solve the issue and teach me about correctly calling classes and when to use a module or a class. 

Thank you very much for your help.